# Sum If but I only want to sum if the referenced equipment is in the list, return an error not a zero if it isn't in the list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the counts for an equipment if the equipment is in the list. I have two lists, one is a partial set, one is the full set. I want to sum the counts from the partial set, next to the main set, but not sum to zero when the equipment is not in the second set.

Example:

Main List

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Equipment | Sum Counts |
| Equip 1 | 5 |
| Equip 2 | Return error, not zero |
| Equip 3 | 3 |

Second List

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| Equipment | Counts |
| Equip 1 | 3 |
| Equip 1 | 2 |
| Equip 3 | 1 |
| Equip 3 | 2 |

`Sumif` doesn't work because it returns a 0 sum when the equipment isn't listed.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you upvoted/accepted the answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `iferror`, `sumif` and `na`:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIF(C2:C5,A2,D2:D5)), NA())
```

So this will return an error if the return value of sumif is 0 since it forces a `#DIV/0!` error.

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Filtered Data (Show Errors)

**Simple (Copy Down)**

```
=SUM(FILTER(D$2:D$5,C$2:C$5=A2))
```

**Spilled (Single Cell)**

```
=LET(slData,C2:C5,srData,D2:D5,dlData,A2:A4,
    BYROW(dlData,LAMBDA(dr,SUM(FILTER(srData,slData=dr)))))
```